# List[String] Object in scala case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am using dse 5.1.0 (packaged with spark 2.0.2.6 and scala 2.11.8).
reading a cassandra table as below.

```
val sparkSession = ...
val rdd1 = sparkSession.table("keyspace.table")
```

This table contains a `List[String]` column, say list1, which I read in scala rdd, say rdd1. But when I try to use encoder, it throws error.

```
val myVoEncoder = Encoders.bean(classOf[myVo])
val dataSet = rdd1.as(myVoEncoder)
```

I have tried with 
`scala.collection.mutable.list`, 
`scala.collection.immutable.list`, 
`scala.collection.list`, 
`Seq`, 
`WrappedArray`. All gave the same error as below.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot infer type for class scala.collection.immutable.List because it is not bean-compliant
```

MyVo.scala

```
case class MyVo(
  @BeanProperty var id: String,
  @BeanProperty var duration: Int,
  @BeanProperty var list1: List[String],
  ) {
  def this() = this("", 0, null)
}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: can you include the schema of your table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Array[String]`:

```
case class MyVo(
  @BeanProperty var id: String,
  @BeanProperty var duration: Int,
  @BeanProperty var list1: Array[String]
) {
  def this() = this("", 0, null)
}
```

although it is important to stress out, that more idiomatic approach would be:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

case class MyVo(
  id: String,
  duration: Int,
  list1: Seq[String]
)

rdd1.as[MyVo]
```

Comment: Thanks @user10758343. `Seq` with importing implicits gave the same error `but Array[String]` worked.

Comment: just a quick question, why Array works with case class and none of the other options that I have listed in the question?